# i am getting list as a output but i haven't converted it to list type

Tags: python, list

i want to get list without using split function . i have found this code in geeks for geeks. i am not
able to understood this code

## Splitting at 3

```
word = 'CatBatSatFatOr'   
print([word[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)])
```

Comment: You're creating a list through a list-comprehension. `[item for item in iterable]` creates a list, and you're simply printing that result

Comment: Also, the `word[i:i+3]` is the slicing mechanism in python (obtaining a `sub-string` from the given `string`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I slice a string every 3 indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711452/how-do-i-slice-a-string-every-3-indices)

Comment: can anyone explain how the code works

Answer (score 0):

You're using `word[i:i+3]` to slice the string and from that, you go through a for loop that iterates `i`, with a difference of 3 between each iteration. Seeing that you didn't understand the code, I suggest you read about [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [for loops](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter5_loops.html).